# SQL Подсчёт количества повторяющихся значений в двух столбцах

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Мне нужно чтобы получилось суммарное количество повторяющихся записей в двух столбцах

```sql
select 'столбец1', 'столбец2', count(*)
from 'таблица'
group by 'столбец1', 'столбец2'
having count(*) > 1
```

Сама таблица на входе выглядит примерно так:

| Заголовок1 | Заголовок2 |
| --- | --- |
| a@mail.ru | b@email.ru |
| c@mail.ru | d@mail.ru |
| b@mail.ru | a@mail.ru |
|  | f@mail.ru |
|  | h@mail.ru |

На выходе выдаёт суммарное количество вместе с пустыми ячейками, либо вообще ничего не выдаёт. Может кто-нибудь подскажет что я не так делаю?

Comment: a@mail.ru в данном случае повторяется?

Comment: Да, b@mail.ru тоже

Comment: Что бы получить количества по одному столбцу, то и в group by должен быть один столбец. А значит получать надо двумя отдельными запросами, которые потом собрать в один запрос согласно тому, что же должно быть в итоге введено. Я вот нпример по вашим данным совершенно не понимаю, какой должен быть получен результат

Comment: Я наверное не очень понятно написала. Должна выводиться сумма совпадений емейлов, в данном случае из двух столбцов. То есть если и в том и в том столбце есть этот емейл.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи нужно использовать `UNION ALL` который в отличие от  `UNION` сохраняет дубликаты значений при слиянии. (я иправил b@email.ru на b@mail.ru видимо была опечатка)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
   Column1 VARCHAR(20),
   Column2 VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2) 
VALUES
('a@mail.ru', 'b@mail.ru'),
('c@mail.ru', 'd@mail.ru'),
('b@mail.ru', 'a@mail.ru'),
('', 'f@mail.ru'),
('', 'h@mail.ru');

SELECT * FROM  /* внешний запрос выборки дубликатов */
  (SELECT Column1 /* внутренний запрос объединение Column2 и Column1 */
   FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
     SELECT Column2
     FROM Table1
  ) as T1 /* задаем алиас для объединенной таблицы */
GROUP BY T1.Column1 /* можно использовать и Column1 */
HAVING Count(Column1) > 1 AND Column1 != '' /* и фильтруем пустые значения*/
```

В данном случае я использовал фильтр `Column1 != ''` если значения могут быть `NULL`, то нужно делать соответствующее сравнение: `Column1 != NULL`

**Результат**:

```
| Column1   |
|-----------|
| a@mail.ru |
| b@mail.ru |
```

Cудя по последнему комментарию еще нужна сумма совпадений, для этого можно использовать во внешнем запросе:

`SELECT *, count(Column1) FROM`

```
|   Column1 | count(Column1) |
|-----------|----------------|
| a@mail.ru |              2 |
| b@mail.ru |              2 |
```

Comment: Спасибо! очень сильно помогли!